# Read Model in Microservice Architecture

Tags: architecture, microservices, event-sourcing

I have a question regarding event sourcing in a microservice architecture.

Suppose that every service stores its own events in a own eventstore, how can i rebuild a read model if the projection needs data from more than one service?

For example we have the UserService and an InvoiceService.
In the invoice service model I work only with the user id, but in the read model I need also the user name for easier queryings.

I thank i have now these options:

1. Store also the user name in the invoice service. Not so good, i think because my source of truth should be still the user service.
2. Create a (rest?) api to fetch the user name from the user service in case of a read model rebuild.

Did I miss something? Does someone know a easier solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that option 1 is unwise.  A domain model (the update model in CQRS, not the read model) should only have primary key pointers into other domains, not supporting data from those domains.

Option 2 is better but still not quite there.  I’m not a fan of API calls between domains when using Event Sourcing because it can cause one domain to fail or appear slow due to the difficulties in the second.  In your example having the Invoice domain call an API on the User domain to get the username for a read model rebuild means that if the User domain is down the Invoice domain cannot complete its rebuild – the Invoice domain fails through no fault of its own.

Consider option 3 of caching the User information in the Invoice domain.  Create listeners to appropriate User events in the Invoice domain and cache the necessary user data there – in this case just the primary key and the username, but you can add more fields later if necessary.  Your Invoice read model is then rebuilt using this cache so there is no dependency on the User domain.

Just a clarifying note to make sure we’re all on the same page, and for those readers who are new to CQRS.  The Invoice read model should have the userid and username in it, but the domain model should only have the userid.  Read models have duplicated information everywhere and are not intended to be third normal form; they are meant to be very fast and contain all information that will be displayed on the screen.

Comment: Yes, option 3 seems to me the best idea. If I want to rebuild my user cache in the invoice service, how can I do that? Is it a good idea just to import the projection with all usernames and ids from the user service?

Comment: You need a "resync" process for the cache tables anyway.  Something that hits the User domain API (that I just said was a bad idea) and updates the cache data just in case. However, this runs nightly or weekly during off hours, and each call resets the cache for one user. You should make this API call a fallback call when the Invoice domain looks in the cache for a user.  If the user is not in the Invoice cache (maybe someone created a user then IMMEDIATELY created an invoice before the CreateUser message came in) you fall back to a live API call to the user Domain.  This should happen rarely.

Comment: Once your resync process is in place, just create a temp script that runs it in a loop for all users.  It will take a while but will eventually get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Users can have more than one invoice and replaying/ rebuilding model from event source with the only username won't be ideal (or at least from my understanding). The route I prefer is to have `a co-relation identifier`. As the name suggests, it shall help you to build a co-relation between service calls/event sourcing records which took place as part of a given business task/action. Having something to co-relate on is important when it comes to re-building model (whether to show in dashboard or logic to perform model/action replay). From a quick search, I found [a talk about](https://hilton.org.uk/blog/microservices-correlation-id) co-relation id. Please go-ahead and read more about it and see whether this approach solve your business problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Yes, one user can have more than one invoice and two users can have the same username. Thats why i use the ids in the model. I'm looking for a good solution for the read model. The read model should have the username too, so I could query easiliy every invoice of users with the name like "exa...". I know I can do that with CQRS - so the services would update the materialized view everytime data changes. But what about rebuilding?

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose that every service stores its own events in a own eventstore,
>   how can i rebuild a read model if the projection needs data from more
>   than one service?

I think you missed the concept of eventstore. Service should not have its own eventstore. Imagine you are publishing an event from your service and some other services will have to subscribe to your event stream. Your eventstore is the single source of truth for all services.

In this way, if you need to create a projection from multiple streams, then you can do that. Please have a look into [this blog post](https://eventstore.org/blog/20130309/projections-7-multiple-streams/).

Now what if you don't want to build projections on eventstore side. Suppose, you have a new requirement to show a report of users containing a invoice count, total bill etc. Then I would do the following -

1. Subscribe to listen UserCreated, UserBasicInfoUpdated events from UserService(new subscription)
2. Subscribe to listen InvoiceGenerated event from InvoiceService(new subscription)
3. Build the new read model
4. Then merge previous subscription(if any) into the new one. This is important. Because you should not have multiple subscribers to the same events.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment! But if I use only one ES, wouldn't that break the idea decoupled microservice system? If I take your second approach - how can I rebuild my read model?

Comment: Basic idea behind decoupled microservice architecture is decoupling boundary of different contexts, hence having different db inside each service on its own is a rule of thumb. But ES stores events in a time series manner and different services need to subscribe different events on different occasions. It is ES' responsibility to publish events to subscribed channels. Using different ES for different microservice will not serve this.

Comment: And following my approach above you can actually rebuild a model. In step 3 instead of creating a new read model, you can update your read model. Something like this "set username=@name where userid=@uid"

Comment: In the end you expose the your persistence layer, comparable to exposing your (relational) database schema in a CRUD based persistence strategy.